# Calculating Vat Rates Based on some variables

Tags: php

The following function is working up to a point where I have to calculate the $vatamount based on some rules.

Ive got all my POST content from a script that fires my ajax request (code below is the code from the ajax URL).

The rules are - If the $bookingtype value is a "Corporate" booking or a "Groups" booking then the vat rate is calculated over the length of stay. 20% for anything up to 28 nights and 4% for anything over 28 nights.

However, if the $bookingtype value is a "Leisure" booking then the vat rate is 20% regardless of the length of stay.

I've got the function to return the right VAT percentage. But that last if statement just isn't working for me. Im a php newbish and i think I've done well to get this far with it. Just need some assistance completing this function. I think I've screwed my syntax in there somewhere lol

The last echo should echo the calculated vat amount.

Thanks in advance.

```
function implement_ajax_vat() {
if(isset($_POST['arrivaldate']))
    {

        //get the start and end dates
        $startdate = ($_POST['arrivaldate']);
        $enddate = ($_POST['leavingdate']);     

        $datetime1 = new DateTime($startdate);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($enddate);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        $numberofnights = $interval->format('%a nights');

        //calculatge the VAT amount
        $bookingtype = ($_POST['bookingtype']);
        $rentalprice = ($_POST['rentalprice']);

            //check numbr of nights
            if($numberofnights >= 29){

                $vatrate = "4";

             } elseif ($numberofnights <= 28) {

                $vatrate = "20";
            }

            //get the booking type and check if its a variable rate

            if(($bookingtype = 'Corporate') || ($bookingtype = 'Groups')){

                $vatamount = ($rentalprice / 100) * $vatrate;

            } elseif ($bookingtype = 'Leisure') {

                $vatamount = "20";

            }

            echo $vatamount;    

    die();
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning values instead of comparing: use double equals sign `==`:

```
if($bookingtype == 'Corporate' || $bookingtype == 'Groups'){
                 ^                              ^       
    $vatamount = ($rentalprice / 100) * $vatrate;

} elseif ($bookingtype == 'Leisure') {
                        ^
    $vatamount = 20;

}
```

That's why first statement yields true as you assign and return there non-empty string, so you never go to elseif section.

Comment: In addition, i also found a £ sign in the value attr in the form. I thought i had it there as a placeholder.

Comment: It's certainly currency, if it is at the end of the amount, the comparison will go well, but you might want to trim it from the amount anyway. Also assigning numbers you should use integers or floats instead of strings: `$vatrate = 20;`.

Comment: Note: Whilst it didnt really answer my question as the reason it wasnt working was due to the £ sign in my form, it has improved my code.